# Writing a touchpad driver for Linux based on published specs

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, touchpad

A friend of mine bought a laptop that unfortunately comes with an unsupported touchpad. The good news is that it comes with [full documentation](http://bydit.com/userfiles/file/BTP10463-XXX.pdf).

1. Is this documentation enough to make a driver with multi-touch support?
2. Is it advisable to base the driver from another (similar) touchpad driver as a starting point? If so, which one shall I use?

Comment: File is not loaded for me. Though usually you don't need to write a complete driver, rather to add few quirks here and there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this controller is already supported by Linux. Just make sure your kernel version is recent enough to have the driver/input/mouse/byd.c source file, and that it is enabled by checking for the presence of the CONFIG_MOUSE_PS2_BYD token in your kernel configuration.